# Hypothetical Church Growth Equation

Tags: summation

To preface this, it's been years since my last calc class, but I feel like this is lower level than that. I am looking for the notation for an equation that sums up the values of the same equation iterated several times, while carrying the last result through the "new" iteration.

I am a programmer at heart, so using "for" statements seems to accomplish this pretty easy, but I need an equation that represents it as well.

So here's the idea: Let's say that we start with 500 people in a church, and over the course of 2 years we assume that each one of those people bring 2 more people who become members which gives you a new church population of 1500, then iterate it again until 6 years have passed.

By the end you should have 13,500 members. It's funny that it's so easy to do in your head, but for the life of me I have no idea how to represent this in an equation. I have tried using a summation to represent the equation using x=2x+x, but I can't figure out how to "notate" x equaling the value of the last iteration with each "new" iteration.

Does this make any sense? I am probably completely wrong trying to use summation notation to do this, but I don't what else to try.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Let $x_n$ be the population after $2n$ years,  Then $x_{n+1}=2x_n+x_n=3x_n$. (This is the mathematical version of your programmer's $x=2x+x$.) So if $x_0=500$, then $x_1=(3)(500)$, $x_2=(3)(3)(500)=(3^2)(500)$, and in general $x_n=(3^n)(500)$.

Answer (score 1):

You have a [geometric progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression) assuming each person only brings in two others and then stops.  In that case you have a tree-you start with $n$, each brings in two so you add $2n$, each of those brings in two so you add $4n$, so you have $n(1+2+4+\dots 2^k)=n(2^{k+1}-1)$ for $k$ doublings.  If the original members keep bringing in newbies, you have a different relation.  It is harder if the originals bring in some members in year 1 who start bringing in newbies in year 2. Your question is not specific enough for that.